# Difference between “/export/home” and “/home”

Tags: solaris, nfs, directory-structure, home

In our UNIX machine my home path looks like `/home/<userid>` and we have another batch user whose home looks like `/export/home/<userid>`

I want to know what's the difference between `/export/home/<userid>` and `/home/<userid>`?

Why there are difference in folders when both are some user in UNIX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Noufal Ibrahim says, I think this is a Solaris convention.

IIRC, `/export/home` is used on the server where the actual files live, and `/home` is where the other servers mount it.

What does `mount | grep home` say?  I'm guessing that `/export/home` has a file system type of `UFS`, and `/home` has a type of `NFS`?

`/etc/fstab` may also have some clues.

Comment: /home should be used on the NFS server too. The automounter should manage the mapping there too.

Answer (score 10):

The idea was/is that `/export/home` is for a physical locally stored home directory. The word 'export' is from the idea that this home directory could be exported to be used from other hosts as well.

`/home` on the other hand would the logical mount for your home directory. You should never physically create home directories in `/home`. It is a place for mounts.

Suppose I have an account on 5 different Solaris hosts. Surely I would like to have only one physical home directory across all those hosts. If the automounter is correctly configured then I would on all 5 hosts see my home directory in `/home` but that is really just a logical mirror. There would probably be one of the 5 hosts that would hold my physical home directory and on that particular host I would also see my home directory in `/export/home`.

If your home directory is always locally stored on the machine then you'll always see `/export/home`.

Too few sites actually centralize home directories in my opinion. But Sun's idea was to use a layout that made such sharing easy and consistent from one host to another. Rarely used and this is the reason that people wonder what it was for.

(Footnote: It was actually only recently, with Solaris 11, that this was made fully consistent so that a user can *always* see his home directory in `/home` no matter if the home directory is locally stored in `/export/home`. This change will make it easier for people from the Linux camp to understand)

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the `/export/home` layout on old Solaris machines that I've used and it was a convention indicating that the partition was exported via. NFS. This is not something that's listed in the FHS so I don't know how "standard" it is really.

Answer (score 3):

Having a home directory being `/export/home/username` is a configuration oddity. The actual directory is located by default here when the user account is created by the `useradd` command but this directory should nevertheless be accessed through `/home/username`.

The convention and best practice is then to have `/home/username` being the home directory and configuring the `automounter` to manage the mapping between both.

By default the automounter master configuration file `/etc/auto_master` contains this line:

```
/home auto_home -nobrowse
```

That means `/home` is handled by the automounter. As a consequence, no directory can be directly created there which is a common source of frustration for novice administrators on Solaris.

The `/home` directory is configured in the `/etc/auto_home` file. It tells the `automounter` where to find the actual directory to mount under `/home`.

For example:

```
vivek nfsserver:/export/home/&
```

tells that vivek's home directory is to be found on `nfsserver` under the `/export/home/vivek` share.

Locally mounted home directories can be configured that way:

```
username localhost:/export/home/&
```

When the `automounter` detects the file server is local, it uses `lofs` instead of `nfs` for performance reasons. These kinds of home directory mounts can also be used with Solaris zones.

Reference: https://c0t0d0s0.org/solaris/english/2008/02/17/less-known-solaris-features-export-home-home-autofs.c0t0d0s0.html

Answer (score 1):

When you create a zone, home directory will be /export/home, so you can use ZFS to protect user's data.