# Can a different path be used in place of /home?

Tags: home

Is it possible to give the functionality of the directory that is typically assigned to `/home` (in distributions like Debian and Ubuntu) to another directory instead (entirely)? For example, if you could do this and you changed it to `/xyz` then all your new human-owned user directories would be installed under `/xyz` (e.g. so Sally's Desktop path would be `/xyz/Sally/Desktop` instead of `/home/Sally/Desktop` and `/home` wouldn't need to exist).

I'm working on a portable program that saves paths and loads them. If it's used on a different computer with a home directory that isn't at `/home` (and consequently there is no `/home`, but rather another path with its functionality), then I'll want it to adjust the path to have the proper home directory location in it for the new computer when the path is loaded instead.

Comment: What is your definition of "user directory" that is different from "home directory"?

Comment: I just mean `/home` by the home directory and `/home/currentUser` for the user directory. I know both words refer to both sometimes, but they are different things, of course. The home directory contains the user directories.

Comment: Then what does your question mean? Is it possible to change the name or path of the directory that is `/home` so it is no longer `/home`? Like changing the number 1 so it is no longer equal to 1, but is equal to 2 instead?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by your example, but my answer is yes if I understood you right, except it's more like changing the variable name than the value (changing x=3 to y=3), unless you consider `/home` to be more like a value since so many people or applications may or may not rely on it being in that spot in a static fashion.

Comment: I'm working on a portable program that saves paths and loads them. If it's used on a different computer with a home directory that isn't at `/home` (and consequently there is no `/home`, but rather another path with its functionality), then I'll want it to adjust the path to have the proper home directory location in it for the new computer when the path is loaded instead.

Comment: you can refer to the $HOME environment variable to obtain the home folder of the currently logged user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Home directories do not need to be placed in `/home` and your program is erroneous if it is hardwiring any such assumptions as that all home directories share a common parent or that that parent is named `/home`.

## `/home` is not even a universal convention.

`/home` was an idea conceived a fair while after Unix was invented.  In early Unices other directories were used.  This can still be seen today on operating systems like FreeBSD (and its derivatives) where `/home` is a symbolic link and user directories actually live under `/usr/home`.

Solaris likewise places "real" home directories in `/export/home` so that `/home` can be full of automatic NFS mounts and suchlike.

## `/home` is not the parent of many common home directories.

There are plenty of home directories that don't live in `/home`.

- The most obvious one is `/root`, the home directory for the superuser, moved from its older location at `/` so that root's personal and "dot" files do not clutter the root directory, but kept on the root volume so that the superuser can log in even when mounting other disc volumes is failing.
- Various dæmon softwares have home directories in other places, for the dedicated accounts that those dæmons run as.

  - qmail's various dæmon accounts use `/var/qmail` for example, or `/var/qmail/alias`.  The latter is even commonly addressed as `~alias` and is *designed* to be a home directory, with `~alias/.qmail` files as in other (real) users' home directories.
  - Various HTTP(S) and FTP(s) server softwares have (official or unofficial) conventions.  For example: home directories for virtual hosts that have dedicated system accounts can be `/var/www` or `/var/www/$VHOST`.
  - Other softwares can be found on various operating systems using home directories for non-personal user accounts such as `/var/unbound`, `/var/db/mysql`, and `/var/db/tor`.
  - Various conventional non-personal user accounts have home directories such as `/sbin`, `/var/adm`, `/var/spool/lpd`, `/var/spool/mail`, `/var/spool/news`, `/var/spool/uucp`, and so forth.
- On OpenBSD the system operator account has the home directory `/operator` and various non-personal user accounts have `/var/empty` as their home directories.

## Home directories do not have to remain in `/home`.

Home directories can be moved after account creation by using the `-d` (`--home`) and `-m` (`--move-home`) options to the `usermod` command on Linux operating systems.

OpenBSD's `usermod` has the same options.  (Don't do the same with the `pw usermod` command on FreeBSD, TrueOS/PC-BSD, et al..  The `-m -d` combination there has a subtly different meaning.)

## Home directories do not have to be created in `/home`.

Even the conventional parent directory used when creating accounts can be changed, and isn't necessarily `/home`.

On Linux operating systems and OpenBSD the `useradd` command's `-b` (`--base-dir`) option specifies the parent in which home directories are created if not explicitly named with `-d` (`--home`).  The *default* base directory is the `base_dir` variable in `/etc/usermgmt.conf` on OpenBSD, and the `HOME` variable in `/etc/default/useradd` on many Linuxes.  A system administrator can change this at whim.

On FreeBSD, TrueOS/PC-BSD, et al. there's a similar `-b` option to the `pw useradd` command and a default for that modifiable via the `home` variable in `/etc/pw.conf`.

## Coping with this

Your program should not hardwire any expectation at all about the locations of home directories or their parents.

- If you want to know the currently logged-in user's home directory, use the `HOME` environment variable.  It's set up by programs such as `login`, `userenv` or `systemd` when the logged-in account is switched to.  If there is no `HOME` environment variable, it's a valid design choice to just abort, on the grounds that the login session environment variables need to be present for your program to run.  Otherwise you can fall back on obtaining the process' effective/real (as appropriate) UID and querying the password database.
- If you want to know a specific user's home directory, query the password database with the `getpwnam()`/`getpwnam_r()` or `getpwuid()`/`getpwiud_r()` library functions and pull out the `pw_dir` field.  (Note that *this field can be NULL or can point to a zero-length string*.)
- If you want to symbolically denote the home directory for a user in a way that is independent of its actual location, you can adopt the convention of a shell-like tilde expansion: `~JdeBP`.  Many programs do this, from `vim` to `mailx`.

## Further reading

- [Difference between “/export/home” and “/home”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11685/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard.  [`userenv`](https://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/userenv.html).  nosh toolset manual pages.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016).  "[False statements about dæmon environments](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/systemd-documentation-errata.html#UserEnvironment)".  *Errata for systemd doco*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Wow! That's a seriously comprehensive answer. Kudos!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to change the user home directory location to some other location, then refer this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user

Comment: And so the answer to *this* question is, "Yes, it is possible for a user to have a home directory other than `/home/<username>`."

Comment: yes.. correct..